# Symfony database setup: command "symfony" in ms-dos doesn't work

Tags: php, database, installation, configure

I am trying to do this:

```
c:\> php symfony configure:database "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jobeet" root mYsEcret
```

This doesnt work for me because it says

```
Could not open input file
```

I thought I needed to add symfony-**file** located in C:\dev\sfprojects\jobeet\lib\vendor\symfony\data\bin\ to PATH, but this didn't do the trick. I tried to enter the whole path to the symfony-file like so:

```
c:\> php C:\dev\sfprojects\jobeet\lib\vendor\symfony\data\bin\symfony\ configure:database "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jobeet" root mYsEcret
```

I get error `Task configure:database not defined`

What should I do in order to:

1. Be able to use the symfony keyword
   rather than the whole path of the
   file
2. Be able to run configure:database?

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
Marius

Comment: Try running "php symfony" from the root of your project folder, and not the one found in the LIB directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be in the directory of your symfony project, in this case `C:\dev\sfprojects\jobeet\`.

Answer (score 0):

"Because the symfony shortcut file is executable, Unix users can replace all occurrences of 'php symfony' by './symfony' from now on.

On Windows you can copy the 'symfony.bat' file to your project and use 'symfony' instead of 'php symfony":

http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/01#chapter_01_sub_application_creation